# Javers ~ Querying the Current State of the repository

Tags: javers

This sounds like something so basic it should be easy, yet somehow I can't figure out how to do it.

Using Javers, how can I get the current state of the repository?

Example: I have three characters, one of that characters gets updated. Now I want to query a list of all characters as they currently are:

```
public class JaversMemoryRepositoryTest {
    private static final String AUTHOR_NAME = "Luther Lansfeld";
    private static Javers javersRepository;
    GameCharacter sylvia;
    GameCharacter bokay;
    GameCharacter cyrus;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUpJaversRepository() {
        javersRepository = JaversBuilder.javers().build();
        sylvia = GameCharacters.sylvia();
        javersRepository.commit(AUTHOR_NAME, sylvia);
        sylvia.name = "Sylvia the Atomic";
        javersRepository.commit(AUTHOR_NAME, sylvia);
        bokay= GameCharacters.bokay();
        javersRepository.commit(AUTHOR_NAME, bokay);
        cyrus= GameCharacters.cyrus();
        javersRepository.commit(AUTHOR_NAME, cyrus);
    }

    @Test
    public void queryShouldFindLatestVersionOfEachCharacter() {
        JqlQuery entryQuery = QueryBuilder.byClass(GameCharacter.class).build();
        List<Shadow<GameCharacter>> gameCharacterShadowList
            = javersRepository.findShadows(entryQuery);
        assertEquals(3, gameCharacterShadowList.size());
    }
}
```

However, that test fails (got 4, expected 3) because I get two shadows for Sylvia.

I know that I could probably solve this with a function that iterates over the shadow, separates them by ID, and leaves only the one with the most recent version, but somehow that feels like overkill for something so basic that I am certain that Javers should have it somewhere.

Maybe something along the lines of:

```
JqlQuery entryQuery = QueryBuilder.byClass(GameCharacter.class).withLatestVersion().build();
```

...except that this doesn't exist. But it's about what I'm trying to do here.

Or the opposite of:

```
JqlQuery entryQuery = QueryBuilder.byClass(GameCharacter.class).withVersion(1).build();
```

...which gets the oldest version of each GameCharacter. I've already tried `withVersion(-1)` for this, but apparently Javers does not counting versions from the end.

Any feedback on this will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Here's a test case that currently crashes as the intended behaviour is not implemented, but would replicate the use case nicely:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import java.util.*;

import org.javers.core.*;
import org.javers.core.metamodel.annotation.Id;
import org.javers.repository.jql.*;
import org.javers.shadow.Shadow;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;

public class GetLatestVersionTest {
    private static final String FIRST_STRING = "This string should be in the end result";
    private static final String SECOND_STRING = "This string will get overwritten with a newer version";
    private static final String THIRD_STRING = "This string should also be in the end result";
    private static final String FOURTH_STRING = "This string should be in the end result as well";
    private static final String AUTHOR_NAME = "Test Author";

    @Test
    public void shouldRetrieveOnlyLatestVersionsOfAllObjects() {
        Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build();
        StringContainer firstObject = new StringContainer(FIRST_STRING);
        javers.commit(AUTHOR_NAME, firstObject);
        StringContainer secondObject = new StringContainer(SECOND_STRING);
        javers.commit(AUTHOR_NAME, secondObject);
        StringContainer thirdObject = new StringContainer(THIRD_STRING);
        javers.commit(AUTHOR_NAME, thirdObject);
        secondObject.string = FOURTH_STRING;
        javers.commit(AUTHOR_NAME, secondObject);
        
        //At this point, some logic is needed that will only query the latest version
        JqlQuery entryQuery = QueryBuilder.byClass(StringContainer.class).withVersion(-1).build();
        List<Shadow<StringContainer>> mostRecentShadows = javers.findShadows(entryQuery);
        
        assertEquals(3, mostRecentShadows.size());
        List<String> mostRecentStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Shadow<StringContainer> shadow : mostRecentShadows) {
            mostRecentStrings.add(shadow.get().string);
        }
        assertTrue(mostRecentStrings.contains(FIRST_STRING));
        assertFalse(mostRecentStrings.contains(SECOND_STRING));
        assertTrue(mostRecentStrings.contains(THIRD_STRING));
        assertTrue(mostRecentStrings.contains(FOURTH_STRING));
    }
}

class StringContainer {
    @Id
    public String string;
    
    public StringContainer(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

The Gradle Dependencies for this are:

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library-distribution'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // Use JUnit test framework
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.0")
    testCompile("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:1.6.0")
    
    //Logging
    compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.25'
    compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
    
    //JaVers
    compile 'org.javers:javers-core:5.10.0'
    compile 'org.javers:javers-persistence-mongo:5.10.0'
}
```

Comment: hi, If you want me to look at your issue, push a runnable test case like these
https://github.com/javers/javers/tree/master/javers-core/src/test/groovy/org/javers/core/cases

Comment: @BartekWalacik : I have prepared a test file that at least works for me locally in my own project, and would love to push it to  to the repository if I knew how. I tried creating a new branch locally and push it to github, but somehow it doesn't show up. I also tried uploading the file directly to github, but github says I'm not allowed to do it because push access is disabled. Anyway, I'll add the file as an edit above, so you can just copy it. Thank you for all your hard work. =^,^=

Answer (score 0):

I have now written a utility class that takes advantage of the fact that shadows are sorted latest-to-oldest to solve this issue with a minimum of hassle:

```
    public static List<Shadow<GameCharacter>> getLatestShadowsFrom(
        List<Shadow<GameCharacter>> gameCharacterShadowList
    ) {
        List<Shadow<GameCharacter>> latestGameCharacterShadows
            = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> registeredGameCharacterShadowIds
            = new ArrayList<>(); 
        for(Shadow<GameCharacter> gameCharacterShadow : gameCharacterShadowList) {
            String gameCharacterId
                = gameCharacterShadow.get()._id;
            if(!registeredGameCharacterShadowIds.contains(gameCharacterId)) {
                registeredGameCharacterShadowIds.add(gameCharacterId);
                latestGameCharacterShadows.add(gameCharacterShadow);
            }
        }
        return latestGameCharacterShadows;
    }
```

Applied like this:

```
    @Test
    public void queryShouldFindLatestVersionOfEachCharacter() {
        JqlQuery entryQuery = QueryBuilder.byClass(GameCharacter.class).build();
        List<Shadow<GameCharacter>> allGameCharacterShadows
            = javersRepository.findShadows(entryQuery);
        List<Shadow<GameCharacter>> latestGameCharacterShadows
            = JaversUtilities.getLatestShadowsFrom(allGameCharacterShadows);
        assertEquals(3, latestGameCharacterShadows.size());
    }
```

The major drawback of this approach, however, is that because this function relies on the _id field of the GameCharacter, I have to create a copy of this function for every object with a diverging ID variable (all those that have the _id field can be grouped in an abstract class after all), so this does not strike me as optimal.

So, if anyone has a better solution, feel free to post it here. I'll still keep this workaround here until then since it gets the job done.